# Java, iterate over an object

Tags: java

I have some JAVA code like the next:

```
public class DataModel {
  public DataModel(OtherDataModel someObject) {
    System.out.println(someObject);
  }
}
```

Debug Output:

```
someObject
--someOtherObject
--ArrayList (related to someOtherObject)
```

I need to iterate over someObject to get an output like this:

```
someOtherObject
-id
-name
-dates (of ArrayList)
--date1
--date2
--dateN
-description
-etc
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From main method, create an object of your class and past that object as a parameter. After that you can access the properties of the object by using getting method.